# Source code of `plot.table`?

Tags: r

How can I see the source of code of the `plot.table` function from the `graphics` package?

Typing `plot.table` or `graphics::plot.table` at the prompt results in

```
Error: object 'plot.table' not found
```

Comment: `getAnywhere(plot.table)`

Comment: or `graphics:::plot.table`